# Menu Cart Tab Plugin. Display Tab After Adding Item to Cart Button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to get the menu cart tab on my site to be displayed as soon as I click on the <kbd>ADD TO CART</kbd> button. Currently, the tab doesn't deploy unless I click on its cart icon (up right side).

I would like something like this (click on add to cart and you will see the menu cart tab on the right side)
https://stacksocial.com/sales/keezel-safe-internet-device-lifetime-vpn-subscription

Comment: What have you tried? Provide an example of what you have tried and which part of your solution are not producing the desired results. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Check out the [tour] and also "[mcve]" and well as "[ask]", and (as suggested above) [edit] your question to show the code you've tried so far, and what's not working in it.